# Unable to access Public DNS and elastic IP in browser

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

I am unable to access my public DNS and elastic IP using browser.

My security group is quick-start which allows: ICMP, HTTP, RDP, DNS

while i am getting response from pinging my elastic IP.

Please help me, as i am new to Amazon EC2.

Comment: Please post your security group info. DNS UDP port 53 should be open, in addition make sure the server you are configuring is linked to the security group you are modifying.

Comment: ICMP
Port (Service) Source Action
ALL 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
TCP
Port (Service) Source Action
22 (SSH) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
80 (HTTP) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
3389 (RDP) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete
UDP
Port (Service) Source Action
53 (DNS) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete

Answer (score 1):

Before you start accessing your public DNS or elastic IP using a browser, which uses port 80 by default, you need to have a service listening on port 80 on your server. Do you have a web server listening on your server? As ping is working for you, it is means the server is accessible from outside.

Also make sure your don't have a local firewall on your server, besides AWS firewall associated with your security group. If you have a local server installed, make sure port 80 or 443 is open.